# Qt Compile Time Error . . 

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt, and I am facing the follwoing error. I have set all the environment variables. I don't know what the problem is. Kindly Help me.

```
11:44:39: Running build steps for project rabiaapp...
11:44:39: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:44:39: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2008\bin\uic.exe ..\rabiaapp\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: cannot open C:\Windows\main.obj.5540.16.jom for write

jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores

jom: C:\Users\rs01\rabiaapp-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 1
11:44:39: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project rabiaapp (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: I noticed "Error: cannot open C:\Windows\main.obj.5540.16.jom for write" this error. 

Why it trying to create object on c:\windows  ?

Comment: Might be that the temp folder is not properly defined.

Comment: Currently experiencing the same nightmare...

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this problem if I check "Clear system environment" on the Projects' Build Settings page. Try unchecking that box.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but this still seems to be the case. I have no recollection of toggling that checkbox since the build last worked, but it was checked, and unchecking it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem. My TMP variable has Chinese characters, which makes qt creator produce error: cannot open ** for write.

Try to change your TMP variable with only English characters, no spaces. Ensure that the folder exists and you have permissions to access it.

My Qt version: Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL). You can set this in Qt Creator

[image: set environment variables in Qt Creator]

Answer (score 0):

Try using nmake instead of jom there should be a checkbox in Settings-> Build and Run -> uncheck use jom instead of nmake.