# Qt Creator build error with under Windows

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt-creator

I want to port a multiple project MSVS solution to Qt Creator.
I created the .pro files for the projects and added them to Qt Creator. 
When I build the projects I always get the same error shown below.
By the way I am using Qt 4.6.3 (VS 2008). What may cause this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what the problem is frmo the jom.exe output.

- It might be that the command it's trying to execute on the console [is too long](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9751) ([MS reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473)).
- A similar problem was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9408466/176769), although is not clear if it was solved.

I suggest you **upgrade to a more recent version of Qt** and try again (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

You could change your make step from jom to nmake (found in the projects window) to see if it gives you a more detailed error.

It also seems that you do not have any source code files in your project, just your library's header files.